# interesting element background-color from stackoverflow list - force change

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to change background color items from stackoverflow main list. I am looking for only items with attribute `tagged-interesting` (topics with orange background).

[image]

I noticed the code works only if I add `alert('elements')`. Without that my code just doesn't start and returns zero amount of found elements.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tagged-interesting');
  //alert('elements');

  var length = elements.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.setAttribute('style', '!important; background-color:#b0ddee; padding:5px')
  }
});
```

---

Changed also to this form but without any result..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tagged-interesting');
  //alert('elements');

  var length = elements.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    var element = elements[i];
    element.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#b0ddee !important; padding:5px;')
  }
});
```

Comment: the `!important` alone doesn't do anything, you need to put that after `#b0ddee` with a space and also put a semi-column  after `5px`

Comment: Where do these `tagged-interesting` come from?

Comment: @dfsq from stackoverflow main page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com
// @version      1.0
// @description  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156245/interesting-element-background-color-from-stackoverflow-list-force-change
// @include      http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @author       zanetu
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.tagged-interesting {background-color:#b0ddee; padding:5px}');
```

Comment: @deadfish Do you have the latest Greasemonkey installed? What browser and operating system are you using? (Please also include version info.) Did you see any error in the browser console? (You can press CTRL+SHIFT+J and paste console output here.) Is the effect below the one you want? ("Jquery" is my favorite tag and hence questions with the "Jquery" tag have the class "tagged-interesting". ) http://i58.tinypic.com/2v2idyh.jpg

Comment: output from console helped me :) there was "GM_addStyle is not definied". I added your grant and it worked finally. Thanks